# Testing elements with jQuery-Chai

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, testem

I have a couple of functions that use jQuery.  And I'm having trouble making sense of the proper way to test them with jQuery-Chai in Mocha+Chai.

I see the list of assertions in the jQuery-Chai plugin.  However, I don't understand where we get the DOM data to run those assertions?

Ideally I want to insert a line of html.  Run the function on it.  And use the jQuery-Chai assertion to validate.

Can someone help clear up where I would include the fixture to test these functions?

Thanks in advance.

Using: Testem with Mocha+Chai.

Comment: I think it only enables you to **use** jQuery in your tests themselves, but has nothing to do with the actual thing you are testing, which is a function in your app which uses jQuery, thus, your function cannot be tested because jQuery will not be defined.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, [chai-jquery](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-jquery) only provides the assertions you can use against DOM elements. You'll need to use a different library to actually populate the DOM. Since you already [need jQuery included for chai-jquery to work](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-jquery#usage), the simplest solution may be to use jQuery's [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function to add child elements to the DOM, then remove them at the end of the test using jQuery's [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function.

Alternatively, if you want to abstract away the DOM manipulation a bit, you could try pulling in a fixtures library. My favorite for this purpose is [js-fixtures](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-fixtures). You can still easily insert a single line of html using the `set()` function if that's all you need:

```
fixtures.set('<div>Your html here</div>');
```

If your test html becomes more complex though, you can extract it out into a sample html file and load the entirety of it into the DOM with the `load()` function:

```
fixtures.load('yourTestPage.html');
```

Finally, when your test is finished, you can easily clean your fixture using `fixtures.cleanUp()`.